# Predicate Logic in Coq

Tags: logic, coq

Can anyone help with these two theorems in regards to predicate logic and using coq. I have trouble understanding coq syntax.

1. exists x:D, (R x /\ S x)  |-  (exists y:D, R y) /\ (exists z:D, S z)
2. exists x:D, (R x \ / S x)  |-  (exists y:D, R y) \ / (exists z:D, S z)

Answer (score 2):

If I understood well, what you're looking for is to prove that if an element satisfies both **Props**, then there is a specific element that satisfies each **Prop** :

```
Lemma and : forall (D:Type)(R S:D -> Prop), 
(exists x:D, (R x /\ S x)) -> (exists y:D, R y) /\ (exists z:D, S z).
```

And that if an element satisfies at least one of the **Props**, then for one of the **Props**, there exists and element that satisfies it :

```
Lemma or : forall (D:Type)(R S:D -> Prop), 
(exists x:D, (R x \/ S x)) -> (exists y:D, R y) \/ (exists z:D, S z).
```

The proofs would then be quite simple, as following :

```
Lemma and : forall (D:Type)(R S:D -> Prop), 
(exists x:D, (R x /\ S x)) -> (exists y:D, R y) /\ (exists z:D, S z).
Proof.
  intros. destruct H. destruct H as [H1 H2].
  split; exists x; [apply H1 | apply H2].
Qed.

Lemma or : forall (D:Type)(R S:D -> Prop), 
(exists x:D, (R x \/ S x)) -> (exists y:D, R y) \/ (exists z:D, S z).
Proof.
  intros. destruct H. 
  destruct H; [left | right]; exists x; apply H.
Qed.
```